# Открыть окно предпросмотра печати в браузере

Tags: javascript, печать

Скажите пожалуйста возможно ли силами js заставить окно для просмотра перед печатью `ctr+P` или `.print()` открываться в зависимости от условий или в альбомном режиме или портретном? Например контента много - альбомном, мало - портретном.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно силами css, управляемыми из js, если требуется:

```
@page {
    size: landscape;   //альбомный режим печати
}
```

[Подробнее про size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page/size). Единственный вопрос тут в совместимости. Здесь пишут, что свойство нигде не поддерживается, несмотря на то что в гугле отлично работает.
Ну и еще - пользователь не сможет изменить выданные вами настройки. Смотрите сами, насколько юзерам будет удобно...